# Ηow to extract particular data from JSON inside JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

A packet contains the data below but I need to extract the following part:

> "data":"YOeNkAAg1wQAYjm/pg==

using JavaScript in node-red. How i can do this?

```
 {
 "payload": "lora/01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01/39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19/packet_sent
{
\"appeui\":\"01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01\", 
\"codr\":\"4/5\",
\"data\":\"YOeNkAAg1wQAYjm/pg==\",
\"datr\":\"SF7BW125\",
\"deveui\":\"39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19\",
\"freq\":868.29999999999995,
\"gweui\":\"00-80-00-00-a0-00-24-6d\",
\"id\":0,
\"ipol\":true,
\"mhdr\":\"60e78d900020d704\",
\"mic\":\"6239bfa6\",
\"modu\":\"LORA\",
\"ncrc\":true,
\"opts\":\"\",
\"port\":0,
\"powe\":11,
\"rfch\":0,
\"seqn\":1239,
\"size\":13,
\"tmst\":3491353235,
\"twnd\":1
}",
  "fromip": "127.0.0.1:35068",
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 35068,
  "_msgid": "193b00a8.e6c4ff"
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: You seem to have JSON inside another JSON: Try with `var payload = JSON.parse(yourObject.payload); var data = payload.data;`, but I suspect the first key `lora/01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01/39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19/packet_sent` to not be valid JSON (missing quotes?)..

Comment: Can you please improve the format? That infinite string is barely readable.

Comment: Ι downvoted because [you did not attempt to solve your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: yes, i tried the same thing but it's giving sytax error:unexpected character

Comment: @Tom We should not encourage questions that show no effort for a solution. I left a comment so that he can improve it.

Comment: @liakoyras YOU are loosing MOST time of us all - answered yet, he got a problem a bit hard to fight with as you can see from answers too, but should he give answer before asking or what ??

Comment: @Tom As far as I am concerned, askers should share every effort they have done researching. A good reason for that is that it demonstrates that the user has taken the time to try to help himself, and saves us from reiterating obvious answers. For example, had the user included that he had tried what the first comment states, we could look for a different answer from the begging and not iterate again and again on already tried solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var src = {
    "payload": "lora/01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01/39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19/packet_sent {\"appeui\":\"01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01\",\"codr\":\"4/5\",\"data\":\"YOeNkAAg1wQAYjm/pg==\",\"datr\":\"SF7BW125\",\"deveui\":\"39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19\",\"freq\":868.29999999999995,\"gweui\":\"00-80-00-00-a0-00-24-6d\",\"id\":0,\"ipol\":true,\"mhdr\":\"60e78d900020d704\",\"mic\":\"6239bfa6\",\"modu\":\"LORA\",\"ncrc\":true,\"opts\":\"\",\"port\":0,\"powe\":11,\"rfch\":0,\"seqn\":1239,\"size\":13,\"tmst\":3491353235,\"twnd\":1}",
    "fromip": "127.0.0.1:35068",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 35068,
    "_msgid": "193b00a8.e6c4ff"
}
var payload = src.payload;
payload = JSON.parse(payload.substr(payload.indexOf('{')));
console.log(payload.data);
console.log('"data":"' + payload.data + '"');
var finalResult = {};
finalResult.data = payload.data;
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult));
```

And after removing this strange part JSON could look like this

```
{
    "payload": {
        "appeui": "01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01",
        "codr": "4/5",
        "data": "YOeNkAAg1wQAYjm/pg==",
        "datr": "SF7BW125",
        "deveui": "39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19",
        "freq": 868.3,
        "gweui": "00-80-00-00-a0-00-24-6d",
        "id": 0,
        "ipol": true,
        "mhdr": "60e78d900020d704",
        "mic": "6239bfa6",
        "modu": "LORA",
        "ncrc": true,
        "opts": "",
        "port": 0,
        "powe": 11,
        "rfch": 0,
        "seqn": 1239,
        "size": 13,
        "tmst": 3491353235,
        "twnd": 1
    },
    "fromip": "127.0.0.1:35068",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 35068,
    "_msgid": "193b00a8.e6c4ff"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the resualt always look like `data...==` you can search in the payload for the content between `data` and `==` with

```
var res = array.payload.substring(
    response.payload.lastIndexOf("data") + -1, 
    response.payload.lastIndexOf("==") + 3
);
```

```js
var response = {
  "payload": "lora/01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01/39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19/packet_sent {\"appeui\":\"01-01-01-01-01-01-01-01\",\"codr\":\"4/5\",\"data\":\"YOeNkAAg1wQAYjm/pg==\",\"datr\":\"SF7BW125\",\"deveui\":\"39-31-37-33-5b-37-67-19\",\"freq\":868.29999999999995,\"gweui\":\"00-80-00-00-a0-00-24-6d\",\"id\":0,\"ipol\":true,\"mhdr\":\"60e78d900020d704\",\"mic\":\"6239bfa6\",\"modu\":\"LORA\",\"ncrc\":true,\"opts\":\"\",\"port\":0,\"powe\":11,\"rfch\":0,\"seqn\":1239,\"size\":13,\"tmst\":3491353235,\"twnd\":1}",
  "fromip": "127.0.0.1:35068",
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 35068,
  "_msgid": "193b00a8.e6c4ff"
}

var res = response.payload.substring(
    response.payload.lastIndexOf("data") + -1, 
    response.payload.lastIndexOf("==") + 3
);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: the `==` is complement added by a conversion to base64 (a sort of padding), it's not guaranteed to be here eevry time.. it will depend on the data

Comment: @Kaddath That is true, but it's almost impossible to retrive the wanted data in any other way without fixing the format